# Will a 800va UPS output 800va after 3 years of usage?

Tags: power, ups

I have been using an apolo 800va UPS for three years for my desktop. During a power outage will the UPS supply 800va to my PC?

When a UPS ages it will decrease the battery backup time but will the 800va be the same?

Answer (score 2):

The output voltage will always be the specified line voltage, and the output current will always be what the load requires as long as that load is less than what the UPS is rated for.  The 800 VA rating represents the load it is designed to handle without overheating or exceeding the component specs.  That doesn't change with age.

That has nothing to do with how much backup time you get, which is what does change.  The amp-hour rating of the internal battery is the measure of capacity, and that determines how long it can supply power.  Battery age and the number of charge cycles reduce that capacity.

BTW, the typical service life of UPS batteries is about three years, so you might want to periodically test your run time so you aren't taken by surprise.  Most UPS batteries can be replaced (they're widely available, even on places like Amazon), and they're a fraction of the cost of a new UPS.  When your run time starts approaching the minimum you need to shut down gracefully, order a replacement battery so you have it on hand.

Comment: Good answer.  Also ambient temperature and temperature extremes will affect battery duration.  Humidity can play a role as well.